# Where can I find the clear definitions for a Couchbase Cluster, Couchbase Node and a Couchbase Bucket?

Tags: couchbase

I am new to Couchbase and NoSQL terminologies. From my understanding a Couchbase node is a single system running a Couchbase Server application and a collection of such nodes having the same data by replication form a Couchbase Cluster.

Also, a Couchbase Bucket is somewhat like a table in RDBMS wherein you put your documents. But how can I relate the Node with the Bucket? Can someone please explain me about it in simple terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- a `Node` is a single machine (1 IP/ hostname) that executes Couchbase Server
- a `Cluster` is a group of `Nodes` that talk together. Data is distributed between the nodes automatically, so the load is balanced. The cluster can also provides replication of data for resilience.
- a `Bucket` is the "logical" entity where your data is stored. It is both a namespace (like a database schema) and a table, to some extent. You can store multiple types of data in a single bucket, it doesn't care what form the data takes as long as it is a **key** and its associated **value** (so you can store users, apples and oranges in a same Bucket).

The bucket acts gives the level of granularity for things like configuration (how much of the available memory do you want to dedicate to this bucket?), replication factor (how many backup copies of each document do you want in other nodes?), password protection...

Note that I said that Buckets where a "logical" entity? They are in fact divided into 1024 virtual fragments which are spread between all the nodes of the cluster (that's how data distribution is achieved).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So the hierarchy is like, Documents are inside buckets, buckets are inside a node and a cluster has multiple nodes. Am I right?

Comment: rather documents are inside a bucket which split between all the nodes in a cluster